# Dagger 2 - Pass FragmentManager to constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm studying the Dagger 2 library and faced a problem of passing parameters which could not be obtained from "extends Application" class.

For example, I need to pass `FragmentManager` to `ViewPager` adapter constructor. **How would you do that?**

**MyApplication**:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private MyAppComponent mMyAppComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    mMyAppComponent= DaggerMyAppComponent.builder()
            .utilityModule(new UtilityModule())
            .locationModule(new LocationModule(context))
            .appModule(new AppModule(context))
            .pagerAdapterModule(new PagerAdapterModule(context)) //this one is problematic
            .build();
}

public MyAppComponent getmMyAppComponent() {
    return mMyAppComponent;
    }
}
```

**MyAppComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = {
            UtilityModule.class,
            LocationModule.class,
            PagerAdapterModule.class,
            AppModule.class
    }
```

)

```
public interface MyComponent {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager(); //is it right?

    public void inject(NavigationActivity navigationActivity);
}
```

**AppModule:**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
Context context;

public AppModule(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Context provideApplicationContext() {
    return context;
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapterModule:**

```
@Module
public class PagerAdapterModule {
Context context;

public PagerAdapterModule(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton TabsPagerAdapter provideTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    return new TabsPagerAdapter(context, fragmentManager);
    }
}
```

**NavigationActivity:**

```
@Inject TabsPagerAdapter mTabsAdapter; //I want this to be initialized
```

Comment: Unless you plan on creating one singleton component per activity you will need another component. You can't provide this from your application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to have a `FragmentActivity` to get a `FragmentManager`, which means you cannot accomplish it in `Application` level, because it's too soon. So you have to create a component dependency from `AppComponent`, let's name it `ActivityComponent`, which will see all dependencies that `AppComponent` provides.

```
@Component(modules = ActivityModule.class, dependencies = MyAppComponent.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    FragmentActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    TabsPagerAdapter provideTabsPagerAdapter() {
        return new TabsPagerAdapter(activity, activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

Now in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityComponent activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                                                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                                                .myAppComponent(MyApplication.getMyAppComponent())
                                                .build();

        activityComponent.inject(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Didn't think about this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have this constructor for viewPagerAdapter and fragment that injected

```
@Inject
DashboardFragment dashboardFragment;

@Inject
public HomeViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager , BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    MyApplication.component.inject(this);
}
```

and create this module

```
        @Module
public class HomeActivityModule {

    @Provides
    HomeViewPageAdapter provideHomeViewPageAdapter(HomeActivity homeActivity) {
        return new HomeViewPageAdapter(homeActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

and provide HomeActivity

```
        @Module
public class HomeActivityModule {

    @Provides
    HomeViewPageAdapter provideHomeViewPageAdapter(HomeActivity homeActivity) {
        return new HomeViewPageAdapter(homeActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

finally in HomeActivity can inject viewPagerAdapter like this

```
@Inject
HomeViewPageAdapter homeViewPageAdapter;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can pass the FragmentManager to the PagerAdapterModule:

```
Context context;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public PagerAdapterModule(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
```

Comment: but how do you pass FragmentManager to constructor then?

Comment: This is not going to work, because `FragmentManager` hasn't been provided from anywhere.